# Perl: server did not recognize the value of http header

Tags: web-services, perl, soap

I'm making my first steps in Perl and I want to consume an existing webservice but it seems that I'm doing something wrong since I keep getting an error "server did not recognize the value of http header". Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use SOAP::Lite 'trace';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx')
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', 'http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx', $_[1] } )
    -> proxy('http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx');

my $method = SOAP::Data->name('GetCityWeatherByZIP')
->attr({xmlns => 'http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/'});

my @params = ( SOAP::Data->name(ZIP => 10007));

print $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not fix the problem with your soap code.
Luckily the service you use also provides a simple interface you cann access with simple GET or POST requests (as described here (http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?op=GetCityWeatherByZIP)

So you coud use:

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $zip = '10007';
my $result = get("http://wsf.cdyne.com//WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP?ZIP=$zip");
print $result;
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WeatherReturn xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
  <Success>true</Success>
  <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
  <State>NY</State>
  <City>New York</City>
  <WeatherStationCity>White Plains</WeatherStationCity>
  <WeatherID>15</WeatherID>
  <Description>N/A</Description>
  <Temperature>63</Temperature>
  <RelativeHumidity>87</RelativeHumidity>
  <Wind>E7</Wind>
  <Pressure>29.97S</Pressure>
  <Visibility />
  <WindChill />
  <Remarks />
</WeatherReturn>
```